# Magento: Get manufacturers that sell a particular product

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to get a collection of distinct manufacturers who sell a certain product type ("backpacks").  The problem is I can either get all the manufacturers, or I can get all the products that are backpacks, but I'm having an ungodly difficult time understanding how to join these collections to get a collection of manufacturers who sell backpacks.

I've gone through 30 different Stack Overflow posts with similar issues and not one has worked.  A common solution in many was the use of:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
```

but `addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')` simply does not work.  My collection of products will not contain the manufacturer id or value.

This code gets all our manufacturers:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
            ->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');

$valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getData('attribute_id'))
            ->setStoreFilter(0, false);
```

This code returns all backpack products:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', '10');
```

I need help to understand either how to get only those manufacturers that sell backpack products via the attribute_option collection, or how to get distinct manufacturers from the collection of backpack products.

Comment: Can you check the product attribute manufacturer "Used in Product Listing" is Yes ? Then try again the first query.

Comment: Is already set to "Yes".  No change.

Comment: Are you sure the `manufacturer` attribute is assigned to your product attribute sets?

Comment: Under edit attribute set, manufacturer is assigned under Groups: General>manufacturer